# In which language/database Visual Foxpro should be Migrated

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I want to know that how we can migrate the desktop application created in Visual Foxpro into any other database/language. Please note that the application is disconnected with internet. (As we can work without internet connectivity) That's a standalone application where currently the files of Fozpro are used.

Please if possible provide any migrating document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo of an application that converts VFP to Servoy: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rUsMMLbcq](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rUsMMLbcqY)Y

I have never used these tools or Servoy nor do I have any financial interest in them - I have just heard other VFP developers talking about them.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't currently any tool that converts a desktop application written in Fox into another language.  You can use the FoxPro wizard and upsize the databases into SQl-Server, but as far as the code itself you have to rewrite.

Comment: I don't think they are looking for an automated tool, just somebody to do it for them.

Comment: That's not what the question says. "how we can migrate the desktop application created in Visual Foxpro into any other database/language" sounds like they're looking for a way to migrate the program into another language.

Comment: You can migrate manually or automatically. I think they were looking into how to do it manually.

Comment: I've never seen any automatic migration program for Visual FoxPro and I've been looking for one for the past 2 years. If you have such a tool please provide the link to it.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dba5c0c6-4416-4449-a153-a9e6c73aeebc/how-i-convert-visual-foxpro-programs-in-c-or-others-language?forum=visualfoxprogeneral

Comment: I didn't say there was an automatic tool. I said the OP didn't *want* an automatic tool.#

Comment: Alan You are Right I didn't need any automated tool. Just I want to Know that whats the way to convert as its really becoming critical to migrating foxpro.

Answer (score 0):

There are many "how" to, but I would go based on your development team skill sets.  Having personally developed with Fox since it was FoxBase back in the late 80's to present, we are in the process of a full rewrite, but so too a completely disconnected environment need, and need to NOT have a "SERVICE" based SQL environment (SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc), we have chosen to use SyBase Database-Advantage Local Server.  It is a stand-alone DLL that allows database connectivity, creation, insert, update, delete, triggers, etc.  A [download is available here](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver/local-server).

Additionally, we are developing in VS2012 using C#.net, WPF using MVVM.  But as others have stated already, there really is no "automated" tool to convert the app, and the only real automated upgrade is with VFP's wizard to upsize to SQL-Server.  However, you could relatively easily use every VFP table and just do a

```
COPY TO YourTable.CSV type CSV
```

TO get a CSV file of all your existing content, then bulk upload into whatever table in whatever final backend you are considering.  One other advantage of SyBase Advantage was that they decided to pick up the slack where VFP was being dropped by Microsoft.  Their engine automatically recognizes the VFP file formats and pulls into their database format so you don't have to.  This definitely opened a door for others in the VFP world for future expansion... They also allow support beyond the 2gig single file format too.  That might be one benefit for you to jump-start your conversion.